# HashTable problems Complexity implementation

Tags: hashtable, complexity-theory

I coded a java implementation of Hashtable, and I want to test the complexity. The hash table is structured as ad array of double linked list(always implemented by me). The dimension of array is m.  I implemented a division hashing function, multiplication one and universal one. For now I'm testing the first one hashing. 
I've developed a testing suite made this way:

```
U (maximum value for a key) = 10000;
m (number of position in the hashkey) = 709;
n (number of element to be inserted) = variable.
```

So I made multiple insert, where gradually I inserted array with different n. I checked the time of execution with the `System.nanoTime()`.

The graph that comes out is the next:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp7Bi.jpg

Supposed that insert is O(1), n insert are O(n). So should this graph be a O(n)?

If I change my values like this:

```
U = 1000000
m = 1009
n = variable-> ( I inserted once for time, array with incrementally dimension by 25000 elements, from the one with 25000 elements to the one with 800000 elements ).
```

The graph i got looks like a little strange:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL1P1.jpg

The unique key of elements to be inserted are chosen pseudo randomly between the universe of key U.
But, with different executions, also if I store the same keys in a file, the behavior of the graph always changes with some peaks.

Hope you may help me. If someone needs code, can comment and I will be pleasure to show.

Comment: *"So should this graph be a O(n)? "* - it's more common to talk about the time per insertion - i.e. O(1) - but it's reasonable to say the *bulk*-insert time varies with table size n - O(n) for that.  The only other thing that approaches being a problem you presumably want insight into is *"behavior of the graph always changes with some peaks"*.  You must expect *some* effectively random "jitter" as the OS, hardware drivers, the virtual machine etc. doing background tasks slows you down: the question is whether the smooth curve shows a clear trend at high `n` values.

Comment: More generally, I suggest you divide you profiling up into two steps: first measure how collision prone your hash function is for some specific set of keys and table size, then that will give you an idea how much linked-list traversal is happening: if the list lengths average O(logN) or even O(log(logN)), you've undermined your overall O(1) performance expectation.  Alternatively, use a good hash function as a reference - make sure you're seeing O(1) with that, then see how much your own hash function implementations increase collisions or degrade performance.

Comment: Thankf forma answering. Do you think, a test madre in C++ would have been more reliable?

Comment: Any language and library usage that does what you ask it to when you ask it to will be more predictable and understandable.  C++ (or C) with a garbage collector library would be little better than Java.  But basically, yes, if you need super accurate microsecond level benchmarking, and no if you just need something good enough to see big-O trends over several-second runs.

Comment: Thanks again. Now it's late to change The entire project. I did it in Java because I had little time to implement and I'm more confidential with it.

Comment: I'm Just afraid my prof could say something about The jvm that conditions performances. Anyway, ypu helped me a Lot. May I ask other questions here, while proceeding on? Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm happy to answer a few questions as I've time, but it's not a discussion forum site and comments that don't relate to the original question are liable to be deleted by moderators.  See how it goes anyway....